# How many moderators do we want?

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

I read the text on the moderator election and did not find the answer to how many moderators we are electing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The election page shows the number of slots the election's being held for — in this case, it's 3:

[image: image with an arrow pointing to where in the UI the number of moderator slots is mentioned]

Answer (score 4):

The default (especially for a new site that's just recently entered Public Beta) is **three**.

When you see fewer than 3, it's usually because one of the 3 diamond mods was kicked out or chose to resign.  When you see more than 3, it's usually for a busier site, and when the existing mods find the workload to be too much. I haven't seen a site as young as Bioacoustics get the approval from the Community Management team to elect a 4th diamond moderator, but I've only been following these things for the last few years.

I think Artificial Intelligence SE might have been the *newest* site to have obtained approval for a 4th diamond moderator.

Comment: do we NEED to have more than 3 nominations? We currently have more-- but I am wondering if there is any benefit or requirement to having >3 nominations? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Shannon For an election with N spots available, there needs to be N+1 candidates, otherwise the nomination period will be extended so that more people can consider nominating themselves. This is just the SE policy. They want elections to be competitive (i.e. more candidates than open positions).